# How does spring handle redirects to internal jsp files?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, redirect

I have a hello.jsp file in my web-inf directory. If my controller returns "redirect:hello", my understanding is that it redirects the browser to perform a get request on the hello.jsp file.

Why does this work? I thought a browser cannot request anything in my web-inf folder. Wouldn't it make more sense to redirect to something publicly accessible like a controller method?

Comment: I have some experience about do redirection to the jsp which is in the WEB-INF folder. I use Struts2 and Spring, write a controller to forward to these jsp. Then, first step is redirect to the controller's method, second step is that the method will forword to those jsps which are in the WEB-INF. So, this looks like using redirect to access the jsps in WEB-INF.

Answer (score 0):

The redirect command sends a 302 (or is it 301?) Location header to the client. In your case it would be the relative URL "hello". This would be relative to whatever URL they are currently at. So if they are at www.example.com/some-url/some-other-url, it would redirect them to www.example.com/some-url/hello .

The browser then makes a GET request to www.example.com/some-url/hello .

If you happen to have a JSP called "hello", that doesn't matter. It's all about the URLs.

Usually, the redirect path is "absolute" meaning with a starting "/", though this is still relative to the context.

Answer (score 0):

`redirect:hello` redirects the browser to a `/hello` URL. It doesn't retrieve a JSP file named `hello`. What you're thinking of is the view resolver which resolves a returned String to the JSP file.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/page1")
public String redirectToHello() {
    return "redirect:hello"; // redirects from /page1 to /hello
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/hello")
public String getHello() {
    return "hello"; // uses a configured view resolver to get a jsp file named hello.jsp
}
```

Take a look at the [JSP view resolvers docs.](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#view-jsp-resolver)

Comment: The redirection will work, but since there is no mapping for `/hello`, you'll get a `404` error.